# How to display message box if text is not one of the specified?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Here is my code:

```
    Dim Seat As String

    Seat = txtSeat.Text.ToUpper

    If Seat = "BOX" Then
        txtPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(75)
    ElseIf Seat = "PAVILION" Then
        txtPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(30)
    ElseIf Seat = "LAWN" Then
        txtPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(21)
    End If
```

My ordeal is I need to display an information/error box when the user does not type one of the specified words. So if I instead type "cat" a message box will appear saying "Please instead type one of the seats in the list :)".

Edit:

That worked perfectly mootinator thankyoU!

Comment: Rather than a textbox that the user has to type a certain string in exactly (meaning no misspellings allowed!), you might consider using a different control, such as option buttons or a combobox. That way, the user can just pick the appropriate option from a pre-defined list. There's no risk of misspellings and they can see a list of the options right in front of them. Things like this go a long way towards user-friendliness and ease of use. Just something to think about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Else
 MessageBox.Show("Please instead type one of the seats in the list :)")
```

Answer (score 0):

See `MessageBox.Show()`, assuming this is a WinForms context.  If web, try jQuery UI's `dialog`.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already have an answer, but here is your answer using "select case" instead of all the if statements.

```
        Dim Seat As String

    Seat = txtSeat.Text.ToUpper

    Select Case Seat
        Case "BOX"
            txtPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(75)
        Case "PAVILION"
            txtPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(30)
        Case "LAWN"
            txtPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(21)
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please instead type one of the seats in the list :)")
    End Select
```